# How to fix not correctly seeking and grabbing a frame in pillow

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, gif

I have a code that uses a gif (https://gifyu.com/image/AH3v) , grabs the specific frame from it  and uses that frame in discord.py api, picture should look something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVyFp.png

the output I get is something like this tho:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZykPo.png

code:

```
img = Image.open("/Users/otonbenda/Desktop/loading bat.gif")
            img.seek(cmdcheck[0])
            buffer = BytesIO()
            img.save(buffer, "png")
            buffer.seek(0)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="idk")
            await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=buffer, filename="whatever.png"))
Please help :)
```

Comment: Please provide the GIF also, since otherwise nobody can help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: @HansHirse https://gifyu.com/image/AH3v